# GROUP_CONCAT is trim my genre

Tags: mysql

How to not trim grop_concat result with searh?

tables

```
idbook
book_id | genre_id
idgenre | genre
```

it's work fine

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS thisgenre,
FROM
    book
        LEFT JOIN
    genre_book ON idbook = book_id
        LEFT JOIN
    genre ON genre_id = idgenre
GROUP BY idbook
```

result

```
horror
horror,drama,mistic
horror,mistic,psihology
```

and when i try to search (`WHERE genre_id = 1`):

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre) AS thisgenre,
FROM
    book
        LEFT JOIN
    genre_book ON idbook = book_id
        LEFT JOIN
    genre ON genre_id = idgenre
WHERE genre_id = 1
GROUP BY idbook
```

result:

```
horror
horror
horror
```

How to get first result with WHERE(or another search)?

Comment: Table structure of genre table ? and also explain what's ur input and what output u r expecting

Comment: @Naruto Do try and use full English words as things like "ur" can be very confusing for people who aren't native English speakers and/or depend on translation tools.

Comment: "How to get first result with WHERE(or another search)?": Just use your first query. Or better explain what you want to get. Your `where`-condition will filter all genres with `id = 1` (`horror`), so you will get just `horror`.